# A Cell in DataGridView opens new form c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am building a windows application with c# in which I have created a database table having following columns: First name,Last name, Donar type,business name,country code,Phone,Date of Registration, Details
The last column text is "Show Details" in each row.
[list of donars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00NWL.jpg)
The purpose for this is, when the 'Show Details' cell of a row is clicked it should take to a new form showing more details about the person.
[donar info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tsym.jpg)
 Also Guide me if it is better to do it as a web application or windows application

Comment: Need more details. Is this a windows form application? wpf?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please give us a [MCVE](https://www.facebook.com/ChrisCrockerOFFICIAL/videos/10154190280664007/)

Comment: in `.net` it just simply `dgclickevent` then `if e.columindex = index of row where button is placed` then `execute code.`